# Video streaming to browser on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, websocket, streaming, media-source

I have implemented video streaming from a Java server to a website using **WebSockets** and Media Source Extensions (JavaScript). This works fine for nearly every browser on several operating systems except **iOS**. I am aware of the fact that MSE is not supported on iOS (yet).

**Is there any way to easily enalbe video streaming for iOS clients using the same (already existing) technology via web sockets?** 
I think of something similar to Media Source Extensions, so that I just have to reimplement the client side.

My workflow is:

1. Create a HTML5 video element and Media Source
2. Create a new web socket and request video data from the server
3. Transcode video using FFmpeg and stream the result to stdout
4. Send the binary video data in chunks to the client
5. Add the video binary data to the source buffer of the HTML5 `<video>` element which is linked to a `MediaSource` with a `SourceBuffer`.

Hoping for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

[If needed, you can use the `<video>` tag](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html). Look under "Provide Alternate Sources", you can use a HTTP live stream.

Comment: I'm already using a `<video>` tag (video data arrive via websocket --> append data to source buffer of media soruce which is linked to the `<video>` element).
HTTP live streaming would be a possibility, but then I would have to implement the whole streaming process for HTTP streaming because I am not possible to communicate via websockets, right?
What I am looking for would be any solution where I can send the transcoded video data via websockets to the client and then add the binary video data to the `<video>` element. Anything like an alternative to MSE.

Comment: @bosboy did you find an alternative? I'd be interested in that

Comment: @Antoine Not really. Looks like streaming video data via Media Source via Websockets to the client is just not possible on iOS. What I have done now is to implement a completely different video streaming technology: HLS (HTTP Live Streaming, introduced by Apple). The disadvantage is that I am using two different streaming technologies now and both use a different communication protocol (Websockets for MSE and HTTP for HLS) but that seemed to be the only way to enable video streaming on iOS, too. Another HTTP streaming protocol instead of HLS would be DAESH.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's why Apple is stonewalling on MSE on iOS is so it pushes more people into using HLS. But I will just make my users pain the pay and try and divert their energy into making Apple support MSE, thanks for the update though

Comment: In my last comment I meant DASH (and not DAESH), of course.